# Route [login] not defined.laraval 6.0

Tags: php, laravel

I make an admin panel using laravel 6.0 I want to make a guard to my admin panel for when trying access without login and then should redirect back to the login page. I tried these code but I got errors. **route defined so I can't figure out the problem.**

this is the error

**Handler.php**

```
Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\RouteNotFoundException
Route [login] not defined.

<?php

namespace App\Exceptions;
use Exception;
use Request;
use Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException;
use Response;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler as ExceptionHandler;
class Handler extends ExceptionHandler
{

protected $dontReport = [

];


protected $dontFlash = [
    'password',
    'password_confirmation',
];


public function report(Exception $exception)
{
    parent::report($exception);
}


public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{
    return parent::render($request, $exception);
}

public function unauthenticated($request, AuthenticationException $exception)
{

    $guard = array_get($exception->guards(), 0);

    switch ($guard) {
        case 'admin':
            return redirect()->guest(route('login'));
        break;

        default:
            return redirect('/user/login');
            break;

    }

}
}
```

**web.php**

```
<?php

Route::prefix('admin')->group(function() {
Auth::routes();
Route::middleware('auth:admin')->group(function() {

Route::get('/', 'DashboardController@index');


Route::resource('/manageSISAccount', 'SISAccountController');

Route::get('/confirm/{id}','SISAccountController@confirm')->name('SIS.confirm');
Route::get('/pendig/{id}','SISAccountController@Pending')->name('SIS.Pending');
Route::get('/shpw/{id}','SISAccountController@show')->name('SIS.show');


Route::get('/logout','AdminUserController@logout');

});

Route::get('/login','AdminUserController@index');
Route::post('/login', 'AdminUserController@store');

});
```

**AdminUserController.php**

```
 namespace App\Http\Controllers;

 use Illuminate\Http\Request;
 use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

 class AdminUserController extends Controller


  {

public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest:admin')->except('logout');
}
public function index(){

    return view('admin.adminlogin');
}
public function store(Request $request) {

    // Validate the user
    $request->validate([
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'password' => 'required'
    ]);

    // Log the user In
    $credentials = $request->only('email','password');

    if (! Auth::guard('admin')->attempt($credentials)) {
        return back()->withErrors([
            'message' => 'Wrong credentials please try again'
        ]);
    }

    // Session message
    session()->flash('msg','You have been logged in');

    return redirect('/admin');

}
public function logout() {
    auth()->guard('admin')->logout();

    session()->flash('msg','You have been logged out');

    return redirect('/admin/login');
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You did not name your login route.

Change:

```php
Route::get('/login','AdminUserController@index');
```

To:

```php
Route::get('/login','AdminUserController@index')->name('login');
```

For more information about naming routes: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/routing#named-routes

Comment: I already tried this but not worked.i got this error  'Call to undefined function App\Exceptions\array_get()'

Comment: @ChamodDilshan That is a different error. As of Laravel 6, `array` helpers are no longer shipped with the framework, you can use `Arr::get` instead.

Comment: I use 'Arr::get' like this '$guard = Arr::get($exception->guards(),0);' I got this error 'Class 'App\Exceptions\Arr' not found'

Comment: You are missing the namespace... Add `use Illuminate\Support\Arr;` with your namespaces.

Answer (score 1):

`Route::get('/login',['uses'=>'AdminUserController@index@index','as'=>'login']);`

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer. Explaining the underlying logic is more important than just giving the code. It helps the author and other readers fix this and similar issues themselves while giving them the clues to the knowledge they need to expand their programming skills.